# What could cause a state chart not to update while training a RL4J model inside Anylogic PLE?

Tags: anylogic, dl4j

I am trying to build a RL model with deep Q-Learning using RL4J in the Anylogic PLE as part of my thesis. Unfortunately, I am not overly familiar with Anylogic and DL4J and therefore might be missing some obvious steps. I only have access to the PLE and therefore I am trying to train the RL model inside Anylogic without the use of custom experiments. I changed the [Vehicle battery example](https://www.anylogic.de/blog/how-to-train-a-policy-for-controlling-a-machine-using-simulation-and-deep-reinforcement-learning/) to be trained inside the Anylogic project's main agent.

The main agent includes a state chart, which is my environment. On top of that functions  `getObservation()`, `takeAction()`, `calcReward()` are implemented here as well. I also included a `resetStateChart()` function to reset my state chart once a final state is reached. All of these functions work fine when I call them manually. The last function inside main is the `train()` function containing all the RL4J code.

Once I start training, the training itself works fine and all the functions get called properly. However, the state chart doesn't update. I invoke the transitions using the `receiveMessage()` function. When I call `takeAction()` manually `receiveMessage()` returns true. When called during training, it returns false. According to the documentation this means that there is no transition inside the state chart, which gets fired by the message. I am unsure how this can be the case as it runs fine when manually called.

Do any of you have an idea what could cause this?

This is my function to take actions:

```java
public void takeAction( int action ) { 

    if (action == 0 || action == 1)
        power -= actionCost;
    else if (action == 2)
        power -= waitCost;
    boolean ret = statechart.receiveMessage(action); 

}
```

This is the code for training the RL model:

```java
void train ( ) {

    MDP<Encodable, Integer, DiscreteSpace> mdp = new MDP<Encodable, Integer, DiscreteSpace>() {
    
        ObservationSpace<Encodable> observationSpace = new ArrayObservationSpace<>(new int[]{13});
        DiscreteSpace actionSpace = new DiscreteSpace(4);
    
        public ObservationSpace<Encodable> getObservationSpace() { return observationSpace;
        }
    
        public DiscreteSpace getActionSpace() { return actionSpace;
        }
    
        public Encodable getObservation() { 
            return new Encodable() {
                double[] a = main_getObservation(); 
                public double[] toArray() { return a; 
                }
            };
        }
    
        public Encodable reset() {
            resetStateChart();
            return getObservation();
        }
    
        public void close(){}
    
        public StepReply<Encodable> step(Integer action) {
            int a = action.intValue();
            takeAction(a);
            double reward = calcReward();
            return new StepReply(getObservation(), reward, isDone(), null);
        }
    
        public boolean isDone(){
            return inState(win) || inState(dead);
        }
    
        public MDP<Encodable, Integer, DiscreteSpace> newInstance() { return null; }
    };

    try{
        DataManager manager = new DataManager(true);
    
        QLearning.QLConfiguration AL_QL = 
            new QLearning.QLConfiguration(
                1,
                10000,
                100000,
                100000,
                128,
                1000,
                10,
                1,
                0.99,
                1.0,
                0.1f,
                30000,
                true
            );
    
        DQNFactoryStdDense.Configuration AL_NET =   
            DQNFactoryStdDense.Configuration.builder()
                .l2(0).updater(new 
                RmsProp(0.001)).numHiddenNodes(300).numLayer(2).build();
            
         QLearningDiscreteDense<Encodable> dql = new QLearningDiscreteDense(mdp, AL_NET, AL_QL, manager);
    
        dql.train();
    
        DQNPolicy<Encodable> pol = dql.getPolicy();
    
        pol.save("Statechart_Policy2.zip");
    
        mdp.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();

}
```

If you need any additional information please let me know.

Looking forward to any hints and thank you!

Edit:

This is my function to reset the state chart to its initial state:

```java
void resetStateChart(  ) { 

boolean ret = statechart.receiveMessage(4);
power = powerCapacity; 

}
```

This is my function to get Observations:

```java
public double[] main_getObservation(  ) { 

    statechart_state[] states = statechart_state.values();
    double[] observation = new double[states.length + 1];

    for (int i=0; i<states.length; i++){
        statechart_state ss = states[i];
        observation[i] = inState(ss) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    observation[observation.length - 1] = power/powerCapacity;

    return observation; 

}
```

[Screenshot of my state chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVg3V.png)

Code of my state chart:

```java
// Statecharts
  public Statechart<statechart_state> statechart = new Statechart<>( this, (short)6 );

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public String getNameOf( Statechart _s ) {
    if(_s == this.statechart) return "statechart";
    return super.getNameOf( _s );
  }

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public int getIdOf( Statechart _s ) {
    if(_s == this.statechart) return 0;
    return super.getIdOf( _s );
  }

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public void executeActionOf( Statechart _s ) {
    if( _s == this.statechart ) {
      enterState( operating, true );
      return;
    }
    super.executeActionOf( _s );
  }

   // States of all statecharts
   
  public enum statechart_state implements IStatechartState<Main, statechart_state> {
    operating,
    recharging,
    reset,
    dead,
    state_1() {
      @Override
      @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
      public statechart_state getContainerState() {
        return operating;
      }
    },
    state_2() {
      @Override
      @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
      public statechart_state getContainerState() {
        return operating;
      }
    },
    state_3() {
      @Override
      @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
      public statechart_state getContainerState() {
        return operating;
      }
    },
    state_4() {
      @Override
      @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
      public statechart_state getContainerState() {
        return operating;
      }
    },
    win() {
      @Override
      @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
      public statechart_state getContainerState() {
        return operating;
      }
    },
    branch() {
      @Override
      @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
      public statechart_state getContainerState() {
        return operating;
      }
    },
    branch1() {
      @Override
      @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
      public statechart_state getContainerState() {
        return operating;
      }
    },
    branch2() {
      @Override
      @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
      public statechart_state getContainerState() {
        return operating;
      }
    };

    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    private Collection<statechart_state> _simpleStatesDeep_xjal;

    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    private Set<statechart_state> _fullState_xjal;

    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    private Set<statechart_state> _statesInside_xjal;

    @Override
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    public Collection<statechart_state> getSimpleStatesDeep() {
      Collection<statechart_state> result = _simpleStatesDeep_xjal;
      if (result == null) {
        _simpleStatesDeep_xjal = result = calculateAllSimpleStatesDeep();
      }
      return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Set<statechart_state> getFullState() {
      Set<statechart_state> result = _fullState_xjal;
      if (result == null) {
        _fullState_xjal = result = calculateFullState();
      }
      return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    public Set<statechart_state> getStatesInside() {
      Set<statechart_state> result = _statesInside_xjal;
      if (result == null) {
        _statesInside_xjal = result = calculateStatesInside();
      }
      return result;
    }

    @Override
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    public Statechart<statechart_state> getStatechart( Main _a ) {
      return _a.statechart;
    }
  }
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state operating = statechart_state.operating;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state recharging = statechart_state.recharging;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state reset = statechart_state.reset;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state dead = statechart_state.dead;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state state_1 = statechart_state.state_1;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state state_2 = statechart_state.state_2;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state state_3 = statechart_state.state_3;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state state_4 = statechart_state.state_4;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state win = statechart_state.win;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state branch = statechart_state.branch;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state branch1 = statechart_state.branch1;
  @AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority(type = AnyLogicCustomProposalPriority.Type.STATIC_ELEMENT)
  public static final statechart_state branch2 = statechart_state.branch2;


  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  private void enterState( statechart_state self, boolean _destination ) {
    switch( self ) {
      case operating:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Composite state)
        trans_op_rech.start();
        trans_op_dead.start();
        trans_op_res.start();
        if ( _destination ) {
           enterState( state_1, true );
        }
        return;
      case recharging:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Simple state (not composite))
        statechart.setActiveState_xjal( recharging );
        trans_rech_op.start();
        trans_rech_rech.start();
        trans_rech_re.start();
        return;
      case reset:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Simple state (not composite))
        statechart.setActiveState_xjal( reset );
        trans_res_op.start();
        return;
      case dead:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Simple state (not composite))
        statechart.setActiveState_xjal( dead );
        trans_dead_res.start();
        return;
      case state_1:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Simple state (not composite))
        statechart.setActiveState_xjal( state_1 );
        {
System.out.println("State1"); 
;}
        trans_1_b.start();
        trans_1_1.start();
        return;
      case state_2:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Simple state (not composite))
        statechart.setActiveState_xjal( state_2 );
        {
System.out.println("State2"); 
;}
        trans_2_b.start();
        trans_2_1.start();
        return;
      case state_3:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Simple state (not composite))
        statechart.setActiveState_xjal( state_3 );
        trans_3_4.start();
        trans_3_2.start();
        trans_3_2_not_wait.start();
        return;
      case state_4:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Simple state (not composite))
        statechart.setActiveState_xjal( state_4 );
        trans_4_b.start();
        trans_4_3.start();
        return;
      case win:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Simple state (not composite))
        statechart.setActiveState_xjal( win );
        return;
      case branch:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Branch)
        if ( 
randomTrue(slipChance) 
 ) { // trans_slip_1
          enterState( state_1, true );
          return;
        }
        // trans_b_2 (default)
          enterState( state_2, true );
        return;
      case branch1:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Branch)
        if ( 
randomTrue(slipChance) 
 ) { // transi_slip_2
          enterState( state_1, true );
          return;
        }
        // trans_b_3 (default)
          enterState( state_3, true );
        return;
      case branch2:
        logToDBEnterState(statechart, self);
        // (Branch)
        if ( 
randomTrue(slipChance) 
 ) { // trans_slip_4
          enterState( state_1, true );
          return;
        }
        // trans_b_w (default)
          enterState( win, true );
        return;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  private void exitState( statechart_state self, Transition _t, boolean _source ) {
    switch( self ) {
      case operating: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Composite state)
        if ( _source ) exitInnerStates(self);
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_op_rech ) trans_op_rech.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_op_dead ) trans_op_dead.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_op_res ) trans_op_res.cancel();
        return;
      case recharging: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Simple state (not composite))
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_rech_op) trans_rech_op.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_rech_rech) trans_rech_rech.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_rech_re) trans_rech_re.cancel();
        return;
      case reset: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Simple state (not composite))
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_res_op) trans_res_op.cancel();
        return;
      case dead: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Simple state (not composite))
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_dead_res) trans_dead_res.cancel();
        return;
      case state_1: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Simple state (not composite))
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_1_b) trans_1_b.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_1_1) trans_1_1.cancel();
        return;
      case state_2: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Simple state (not composite))
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_2_b) trans_2_b.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_2_1) trans_2_1.cancel();
        return;
      case state_3: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Simple state (not composite))
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_3_4) trans_3_4.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_3_2) trans_3_2.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_3_2_not_wait) trans_3_2_not_wait.cancel();
        return;
      case state_4: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Simple state (not composite))
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_4_b) trans_4_b.cancel();
        if ( !_source || _t != trans_4_3) trans_4_3.cancel();
        return;
      case win: 
        logToDBExitState(statechart, self);
        logToDB(statechart, _t, self);
      // (Simple state (not composite))
        return;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  private void exitInnerStates( statechart_state _destination ) {
    statechart_state _state = statechart.getActiveSimpleState();
    while( _state != _destination ) {
            exitState( _state, null, false );
            _state = _state.getContainerState();
        }
    }
  
  public TransitionTimeout trans_rech_rech = new TransitionTimeout( this );
  public TransitionTimeout trans_3_4 = new TransitionTimeout( this );

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public String getNameOf( TransitionTimeout _t ) {
    if ( _t == trans_rech_rech ) return "trans_rech_rech";
    if ( _t == trans_3_4 ) return "trans_3_4";
    return super.getNameOf( _t );
  }

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public Statechart getStatechartOf( TransitionTimeout _t ) { 
    if ( _t == trans_rech_rech ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_3_4 ) return statechart;
    return super.getStatechartOf( _t );
  }

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public void executeActionOf( TransitionTimeout self ) {
    if ( self == trans_rech_rech ) {
      {
power = limitMax(power+25, powerCapacity) 
;}
      trans_rech_rech.start();
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_3_4 ) {
      exitState( state_3, self, true );
          enterState( state_4, true );
      return;
    }
    super.executeActionOf( self );
  }
  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public double evaluateTimeoutOf( TransitionTimeout _t ) {
    double _value;
    if ( _t == trans_rech_rech ) {
      _value = 
1 
;
      _value = toModelTime( _value, SECOND );
      return _value;
    }
    if ( _t == trans_3_4 ) {
      _value = 
5 
;
      _value = toModelTime( _value, SECOND );
      return _value;
    }
    return super.evaluateTimeoutOf( _t );
  }

  public TransitionCondition trans_res_op = new TransitionCondition( this );
  public TransitionCondition trans_op_dead = new TransitionCondition( this );

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public String getNameOf( TransitionCondition _t ) {
    if ( _t == trans_res_op ) return "trans_res_op";
    if ( _t == trans_op_dead ) return "trans_op_dead";
    return super.getNameOf( _t );
  }

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public Statechart getStatechartOf( TransitionCondition _t ) { 
    if ( _t == trans_res_op ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_op_dead ) return statechart;
    return super.getStatechartOf( _t );
  }

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public void executeActionOf( TransitionCondition self ) {
    if ( self == trans_res_op ) {
      exitState( reset, self, true );
          enterState( operating, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_op_dead ) {
      exitState( operating, self, true );
          enterState( dead, true );
      return;
    }
    super.executeActionOf( self );
  }
  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public boolean testConditionOf( TransitionCondition _t ) {
    if ( _t == trans_res_op ) return 
true 
;
    if ( _t == trans_op_dead ) return 
power <= 0  
;
    return super.testConditionOf( _t );
  }


  public TransitionMessage trans_op_rech = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_rech_op = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_rech_re = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_dead_res = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_op_res = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_1_b = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_2_b = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_4_b = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_4_3 = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_3_2 = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_3_2_not_wait = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_2_1 = new TransitionMessage( this );
  public TransitionMessage trans_1_1 = new TransitionMessage( this );

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public String getNameOf( TransitionMessage _t ) {
    if ( _t == trans_op_rech ) return "trans_op_rech";
    if ( _t == trans_rech_op ) return "trans_rech_op";
    if ( _t == trans_rech_re ) return "trans_rech_re";
    if ( _t == trans_dead_res ) return "trans_dead_res";
    if ( _t == trans_op_res ) return "trans_op_res";
    if ( _t == trans_1_b ) return "trans_1_b";
    if ( _t == trans_2_b ) return "trans_2_b";
    if ( _t == trans_4_b ) return "trans_4_b";
    if ( _t == trans_4_3 ) return "trans_4_3";
    if ( _t == trans_3_2 ) return "trans_3_2";
    if ( _t == trans_3_2_not_wait ) return "trans_3_2_not_wait";
    if ( _t == trans_2_1 ) return "trans_2_1";
    if ( _t == trans_1_1 ) return "trans_1_1";
    return super.getNameOf( _t );
  }

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public Statechart getStatechartOf( TransitionMessage _t ) { 
    if ( _t == trans_op_rech ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_rech_op ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_rech_re ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_dead_res ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_op_res ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_1_b ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_2_b ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_4_b ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_4_3 ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_3_2 ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_3_2_not_wait ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_2_1 ) return statechart;
    if ( _t == trans_1_1 ) return statechart;
    return super.getStatechartOf( _t );
  }

  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public void executeActionOf( TransitionMessage self, Object _msg ) {
    if ( self == trans_op_rech ) {
      exitState( operating, self, true );
          enterState( recharging, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_rech_op ) {
      exitState( recharging, self, true );
          enterState( operating, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_rech_re ) {
      exitState( recharging, self, true );
          enterState( reset, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_dead_res ) {
      exitState( dead, self, true );
          enterState( reset, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_op_res ) {
      exitState( operating, self, true );
          enterState( reset, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_1_b ) {
      exitState( state_1, self, true );
      {
        Integer msg = (Integer) _msg;
System.out.println("Action"); 
;}
          enterState( branch, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_2_b ) {
      exitState( state_2, self, true );
          enterState( branch1, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_4_b ) {
      exitState( state_4, self, true );
          enterState( branch2, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_4_3 ) {
      exitState( state_4, self, true );
          enterState( state_3, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_3_2 ) {
      exitState( state_3, self, true );
          enterState( state_2, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_3_2_not_wait ) {
      exitState( state_3, self, true );
          enterState( state_2, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_2_1 ) {
      exitState( state_2, self, true );
          enterState( state_1, true );
      return;
    }
    if ( self == trans_1_1 ) {
      exitState( state_1, self, true );
          enterState( state_1, true );
      return;
    }
    super.executeActionOf( self, _msg );
  }
  @Override
  @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
  public boolean testMessageOf( TransitionMessage _t, Object _msg ) {
    if ( _t == trans_op_rech ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
3 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_rech_op ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
3 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_rech_re ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
4 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_dead_res ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
4 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_op_res ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
4 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_1_b ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
0 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_2_b ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
0 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_4_b ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
0 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_4_3 ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
1 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_3_2 ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
1 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_3_2_not_wait ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
0 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_2_1 ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
1 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    if ( _t == trans_1_1 ) {
      if ( !(_msg instanceof Integer) )
        return false;
      
Integer 
msg = (Integer) _msg;
      Object _g = 
1 
;
      return msg.equals( _g );
    }
    return super.testMessageOf( _t, _msg );
  }
```

Comment: what is the resetStateChart function?

Comment: I edited my question to include the code for my reset and observation function. The reset function has two steps. The first is to change the state chart to the original state. This is done by triggering a transition which changes the state to a reset state from where it automatically transitions back to the starting state. The second step is to reset the power level.

Comment: what does this do? statechart.receiveMessage(4); (show code and statechart)

Comment: I included a link to the screenshot of my state chart to my question. I wasn't sure which code exactly you meant. I uploaded the complete code regarding the state chart from Anylogic. If you were talking about different code please let me know. There aren't any actions performed inside the transition to and from the reset state or inside the reset state itself.

Comment: the statechart.receiveMessage(4) triggers any of the three transition to the reset state. either from the operating, dead or recharging state

Comment: i mean what is the 4 in the receiveMessage... why do you choose a 4, and what does the 4 do in the statechart.... I don't see any way in which that statechart can be reset though

Comment: I set up the transitions to the reset state to get triggered when they receive a particular message with the content 4. 4 is simply chosen because I already had 4 other actions defined (0 = forward, 1 = backward, 2 = wait, 3 = recharge mode). I uploaded a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/nK4jUyu) of the transition properties.

Comment: The other transitions to the reset state are identical. My train of thought regarding the reset was, that after the transition to the reset state (by `receiveMessage(4)`), the transition out of it back to the operating state has the condition true, so it gets triggered immediately. In my operating state the initial state state_1 becomes active. As I am back in the original state i thought I had effectively reset the state chart. Is this a good work around in your opinion or should I have done it differently?

Comment: the conditional trigger is probably not working... change it to be a message trigger and use a message accordingly to move from reset back to the operating state

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I double checked and it seems to be that the ML model calls the functions to interact with the state chart correctly, but the state chart never seems to receive the messages/ change states. For example at the start of training `reset()` and with that `resetStateChart()` get called, which worked, but the state chart never transitions to the reset state. Could it be that the messages get fired so quickly, that the state chart can't keep up or doesn't have time to update? I tried changing to fireEvent() instead of receiveMessage() but that didn't help.